# Pulling a variable out of Promise when querying data from Firestore Firebase database - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let savedArrayUID = []; let savedArrayEmails = [];

function pullIt(emailSearch) {

    db.collection(collectionName).where('email', '==', emailSearch).get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                savedArrayUID.push(doc.id);
                savedArrayEmails.push(doc.data());
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                // saved.   push(doc.id);
                return savedArrayUID; 
            })
        });
}
```

I can query the data from the database but cannot pull the variable out of the scope of the function.
I want to use this function to pass through emails to find info of their profile saved in my Database.

I really struggle to understand how Promiseses can help here. I have a feeling this is already solved, but I could not find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's two steps to this:

1. Ensure that your data makes it out of your `pullIt` (as a promise).
2. Then call that `pullIt` correctly, waiting for the promise to resolve.

In code, you're missing a top-level return the `pullIt` code:

```
function pullIt(emailSearch) {
    // 
    return db.collection(collectionName).where('email', '==', emailSearch).get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                savedArrayUID.push(doc.id);
                savedArrayEmails.push(doc.data());
            })
            return savedArrayUID; // 
        });
}
```

And then when calling `pullIt`, you'll need to use either `await` or `then`, to ensure `pullIt` completed before you try to access the result.

So either:

```
pullIt("yourSearchTeam").then((results) => {
  // TODO: use your results here
})
```

Or (in an `async` context):

```
const results = await pullIt("yourSearchTeam")

// TODO: use your results here
```

Comment: Thanks Phil. I fixed one problem in the first snippet that would indeed make `pullIt` return no result. If there are more issues, please let me know, suggest an edit to my answer or post another answer to the problem.

Comment: It does define results when using ```async``` before ```(results)```

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @ChristianBear. I'm not sure I follow where you added `async` though, so if that's code that's in my answer, can you propose an edit with the change?